# $E$ be a domain, define $E^*=\{z \in C: \overline{z}\in E\}$ $f: E \to C$ is analytic, then $f^*(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ analytic on $E*$.

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that since $f$ is analytic on $E$ we have

$$u_x=v_y \quad u_y=-v_x$$

We have $f^*(z)=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$

Essentially we are going from

$$E^* \stackrel{\overline{z}}{\rightarrow} E \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{C} \stackrel{\overline{z}}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{C}$$

and $f$ is analytic on $E$. While $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is not analytic we are doing that mapping twice so it may not disturb analyticity?

I know I need to consider the Cauchy-Riemann equations on $f^*$ but I'm not sure how to get there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is a composition of an antiholomorphic map, with a holomorphic map, with an antiholomorphic map again.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Well, it shows that the function is holomorphic. What else are you asking?

Comment: I'm unsure of how that demonstrates that?

Comment: The composition of two antilinear maps will be linear. Apply it to $\mathbf{C}$-linear maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}\, f^*(z), V(x,y)=\operatorname{Im}\, f^*(z).$
Then \begin{align}
&U(x,y)=u(x,-y),\quad V(x,y)=-v(x,-y),\\
&f^*(z)=U(x,y)+iV(x,y).
\end{align}
We consider the Cauchy-Riemann equations on $U$ and $V$. By the chain rule we have 
\begin{align}
U_x&=u_x(x,-y),\\
U_y&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u(x,-y))=u_y(x,-y)\times (-1)=-u_y(x,-y),\\
V_x&=-v_x(x,-y),\\
V_y&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-v(x,-y))=-v_y(x,-y)\times (-1)=v_y(x,-y),
\end{align}
where $\times (-1)$ comes from $\frac{\partial(-y)}{\partial y}=-1$. 
Therefore we have $$
U_x=V_y,\quad U_y=-V_x,
$$
since $u, v$ satisfy $u_x=v_y,\, u_y=-v_x.$